Why do homemade cleaning products often have both a base and an acid in them?
I received a kit to make DIY cleaning products. This kit contained a "recipes pamphlet" which, from a chemistry standpoint, I struggle to make sense of.
For example, the recipe to make dishwashing solid capsules is:

90g Sodium Carbonate  - 0.849 moles  pka:10.3
90g Citric acid   -  0.469 moles  pka1: 3.1
40 g Sodium bicarbonate   - 0.476 moles pka:6.4
50g Sodium percarbonate - 0.318 moles  pka: 10.3

Method: Add everything together and spray lightly with water as to make a foam, then place in a ice cube tray ON.
From what I have gathered, citric acid is typically used to remove calcium carbonate, even if according to some other threads, dishwashers normally use a softener to avoid its formation.
Alkaline solutions on the other hand  "usually cause a faster hydrolysis of the amide bonds in proteins than acids." - cbeleites
Why are the majority of cleaning solutions basic?
Sodium percarbonate is a source of hydrogen peroxide and therefore used as an oxidant.
There a few things that are not clear to me.
Firstly, considering there is more than twice as much sodium carbonate as citric acid and that the delta pka is bigger than 3, I expect a complete neutralization of the citric acid and localised heat generation (the solid capsule is inside the dishwasher, the water is sprayed, neutralization occurs where the capsule is. Note that dishwashers operate at ~60°C so I don't even think this is relevant). Hence, I don't understand the point of adding citric acid. Furthermore, even if the carbonate/ bicarbonate acts as a buffer, addition of citric acid will just reduce the alkaline power of the mixture.
I also struggle to understand the chemistry of detergents since we use single small molecules (i.e sodium bicarbonate) to treat complex macrostructures (i.e food). I therefore do not comprehend the mechanisms by which these small molecules manage to break down all kinds of foods, greases etc. For example, what types of foods are we targeting with hydrogen peroxide? Do we know that it works empirically or are there articles that demonstrate its general power against complex macrostructure such as food?
Any answer which will help me understand this recipe will be highly appreciated.
Any good books on the chemistry of homemade cleaning products is also appreciated.
The reference for this recipe was not provided as the company which furnished the kit no longer exists.
Thank you

What makes you think some "homemade cleaning product" would be any good? Acid + (bi)carbonate are for foam, so it looks like it's working. Whether it would is another matter.

And detergents are the thing to wash the dishes, not some dubious mixtures.

You start with the assumption that DIY recipes have a good chemical rationale and are not just some snake oil bullshit. That is a false assumption. You would do better to compare the ingredient list of commercial products where there is more rationale for the mix actually working.
